# Did I relaunch / reconfigure every launchctl daemon here?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, daemons, launchctl

I accidentally issue the following command:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

The output:

```
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
com.apple.ActivityMonitor: Already loaded
com.apple.afpfs_afpLoad: Already loaded
com.apple.afpfs_checkafp: Already loaded
com.apple.AirPlayXPCHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.AirPort.wps: Already loaded
com.apple.airportd: Already loaded
com.apple.airport.updateprefs: Already loaded
com.apple.alf: Already loaded
com.apple.AOSNotification-FMM: Already loaded
com.apple.appleprofilepolicyd: Already loaded
com.apple.apsd: Already loaded
com.apple.aslmanager: Already loaded
com.apple.audio.coreaudiod: Already loaded
com.apple.auditd: Already loaded
com.apple.authorizationhost: Already loaded
com.apple.autofsd: Already loaded
com.apple.automountd: Already loaded
com.apple.avbdeviced: Already loaded
com.apple.awacsd: Already loaded
com.apple.backupd: Already loaded
com.apple.blued: Already loaded
com.apple.bnepd: Already loaded
com.apple.bsd.dirhelper: Already loaded
com.apple.bsd.launchdadd: Already loaded
com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.cmio.AVCAssistant: Already loaded
com.apple.cmio.IIDCVideoAssistant: Already loaded
com.apple.cmio.VDCAssistant: Already loaded
com.apple.configd: Already loaded
com.apple.CoreRAID: Already loaded
com.apple.coreservices.appleevents: Already loaded
com.apple.coreservices.appleid.passwordcheck: Already loaded
com.apple.coreservicesd: Already loaded
com.apple.corestorage.corestoraged: Already loaded
com.apple.corestorage.corestoragehelperd: Already loaded
com.apple.coresymbolicationd: Already loaded
com.apple.cvmsServ: Already loaded
com.apple.DiagnosticReportCleanUp: Already loaded
com.apple.diskarbitrationd: Already loaded
com.apple.diskmanagementd: Already loaded
com.apple.distnoted.xpc.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.dpd: Already loaded
com.apple.dspluginhelperd: Already loaded
com.apple.DumpGPURestart: Already loaded
com.apple.DumpPanic: Already loaded
com.apple.dvdplayback.setregion: Already loaded
com.apple.dynamic_pager: Already loaded
com.apple.eapolcfg_auth: Already loaded
com.apple.efilogin-helper: Already loaded
com.apple.emond.aslmanager: Already loaded
com.apple.emond: Already loaded
com.apple.familycontrols: Already loaded
com.apple.FileCoordination: Already loaded
com.apple.findmymacd: Already loaded
com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
com.apple.fontd: Already loaded
com.apple.fontmover: Already loaded
com.apple.FontWorker: Already loaded
com.apple.fseventsd: Already loaded
com.apple.geod: Already loaded
com.apple.gkreport: Already loaded
com.apple.gssd: Already loaded
com.apple.hdiejectd: Already loaded
com.apple.hidd: Already loaded
com.apple.IFCStart: Already loaded
com.apple.installd: Already loaded
com.apple.kcproxy: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.digest-service: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kadmind: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kcm: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kdc: Already loaded
com.apple.Kerberos.kpasswdd: Already loaded
com.apple.KernelEventAgent: Already loaded
com.apple.kextd: Already loaded
com.apple.kuncd: Already loaded
com.apple.locate: Already loaded
com.apple.locationd: Already loaded
com.apple.lockd: Already loaded
com.apple.locum: Already loaded
com.apple.logind: Already loaded
com.apple.loginwindow: Already loaded
com.apple.ManagedClient: Already loaded
com.apple.mbicloudsetupd: Already loaded
com.apple.mdmclient.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.mDNSResponder: Already loaded
com.apple.mDNSResponderHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.metadata.mds: Already loaded
com.apple.metadata.mds.scan: Already loaded
com.apple.metadata.mds.spindump: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.lsarpc: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.mdssvc: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.netlogon: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.srvsvc: Already loaded
com.apple.msrpc.wkssvc: Already loaded
com.apple.netauth.sys.auth: Already loaded
com.apple.netauth.sys.gui: Already loaded
com.apple.netbiosd: Already loaded
com.apple.networkd: Already loaded
com.apple.networkd_privileged: Already loaded
com.apple.NetworkDiagnostics: Already loaded
com.apple.nlcd: Already loaded
com.apple.newsyslog: Already loaded
com.apple.nfsconf: Already loaded
com.apple.nfsd: Already loaded
com.apple.nis.ypbind: Already loaded
com.apple.notifyd: Already loaded
com.apple.ocspd: Already loaded
com.apple.opendirectoryd: Already loaded
com.apple.PCIELaneConfigTool: Already loaded
com.apple.periodic-daily: Already loaded
com.apple.periodic-monthly: Already loaded
com.apple.periodic-weekly: Already loaded
com.apple.pfctl: Already loaded
com.apple.platform.ptmd: Already loaded
com.apple.powerd: Already loaded
com.apple.preferences.timezone.admintool: Already loaded
com.apple.preferences.timezone.auto: Already loaded
com.apple.printtool.daemon: Already loaded
com.apple.racoon: Already loaded
com.apple.RemoteDesktop.PrivilegeProxy: Already loaded
com.apple.RemotePairTool: Already loaded
com.apple.ReportCrash.Root: Already loaded
com.apple.revisiond: Already loaded
com.apple.RFBEventHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.rpcbind: Already loaded
com.apple.rpmuxd: Already loaded
com.apple.sandboxd: Already loaded
com.apple.SCHelper: Already loaded
com.apple.scsid: Already loaded
com.apple.secd: Already loaded
com.apple.security.syspolicy: Already loaded
com.apple.SecurityAgent: Already loaded
com.apple.securityd: Already loaded
com.apple.ServerPerfLog.aslmanager: Already loaded
com.apple.ServerPerfLog: Already loaded
com.apple.shutdown_monitor: Already loaded
com.apple.sleepservicesd: Already loaded
com.apple.smb.preferences: Already loaded
com.apple.softwareupdatecheck.initial: Already loaded
com.apple.softwareupdatecheck.periodic: Already loaded
com.apple.spindump: Already loaded
com.apple.spindump_symbolicator: Already loaded
com.apple.stackshot: Already loaded
com.apple.statd.notify: Already loaded
com.apple.storereceiptinstaller: Already loaded
com.apple.suhelperd: Already loaded
com.apple.syslogd: Already loaded
com.apple.sysmond: Already loaded
com.apple.systemkeychain: Already loaded
com.apple.systempreferences.install: Already loaded
com.apple.systempreferences.writeconfig: Already loaded
com.apple.SystemStarter: Already loaded
com.apple.taskgated-helper: Already loaded
com.apple.taskgated: Already loaded
com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent.system: Already loaded
com.apple.ucupdate.plist: Already loaded
com.apple.uninstalld: Already loaded
com.apple.unmountassistant.sysagent: Already loaded
com.apple.usbmuxd: Already loaded
com.apple.UserEventAgent-System: Already loaded
com.apple.UserNotificationCenter: Already loaded
com.apple.var-db-dslocal-backup: Already loaded
com.apple.vsdbutil: Already loaded
com.apple.warmd: Already loaded
com.apple.webdavfs_load_kext: Already loaded
com.apple.wifid: Already loaded
com.apple.WindowServer: Already loaded
com.apple.xpcd: Already loaded
com.apple.xprotectupdater: Already loaded
com.vix.cron: Already loaded
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
org.cups.cupsd: Already loaded
org.ntp.ntpd: Already loaded
org.postfix.master: Already loaded
```

Did I launched or configured every Daemon in that LaunchDaemons directory? If yes, how do I restore the previous condition, is there a list of default startup launch daemons for lion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

> After the system is booted and the kernel is running, `launchd` loads
>   the parameters for each launch-on-demand system-level daemon from the
>   property list files found in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ and
>   /Library/LaunchDaemons/.

```
com.apple.ActivityMonitor: Already loaded // This means daemon is already loaded
```